# Tune expensive query

Tags: sql, performance

I've got a query:

```
SELECT MIN(Numero) 
FROM view_OperatoriCpuLiberi 
WHERE IDCpu = '9e2da792-be47-e311-aea8-b4b52fb677e0' 
AND Numero > 100 AND IDGruppo IN 
(
    SELECT AssociazioniCampo.IDOggetto AS IDGruppiAutorizzati 
    FROM Anag.ListeAssociazioni 
    INNER JOIN Anag.AssociazioniCampo ON ListeAssociazioni.IDLista = AssociazioniCampo.IDLista 
    INNER JOIN Campo.Oggetti ON AssociazioniCampo.IDOggetto = Oggetti.IDOggetto 
    WHERE ListeAssociazioni.IDTipoMacroOggetto = 5 
    AND ListeAssociazioni.IDTipoAssociatoCampo = 74 
    AND Deleted = 0 
    AND IDMacroOggetto = 'c3f2c542-a195-11e0-a2e3-000c2962b9f0'
)
```

The 'view_OperatoriCpuLiberi' contains 81981 rows and the nested query (between parenthesis) 861 rows. The query took more then 2 seconds. If I remove the nested query and then the 'IDGruppo IN' instruction it became very fast. What I can do?

Comment: What database are you using?  And can you post your table structures and any indexes on the tables? Thanks.

Comment: don't see any reason that has to be a subselect. it could be re-written as a plain join...

Comment: Ya, I feel like it depends on your DB but I seem to recall that older versions of SQL took pretty big performance hits for Subqueries in the Where clause.  Try moving the subquery into your FROM clause and then JOIN it, as per Marc B's suggestion.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008R2, ok I try to translate it in a plain join query and give feedback

Comment: In addition to table structures and indexes, it's also usually a good idea when asking for performance help to include the query plan for your query.

Comment: Does the sub-query return a guaranteed 861 ***unique*** values, or could there be repetitions within those 861 values?  If there are no repetitions then I'd be confident that using a join will allow a much cleaner execution plan.

Comment: This is the old and the new result:  SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 686 ms,  elapsed time = 689 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 94 ms,  elapsed time = 98 ms.

Comment: The plain version took 94ms instead 686ms!! Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would probably write this query, although whether or not it performs better might depend on how things are indexed, etc.

You didn't use aliases on all of your columns, so I had to guess where some of them were coming from.

```
SELECT
    MIN(OCL.Numero) 
FROM
    view_OperatoriCpuLiberi OCL -- Ugh. Object name prefixes are evil.
INNER JOIN Anag.AssociazioniCampo AC ON
    AC.IDOggetto = OCL.IDGruppo
INNER JOIN Anag.ListeAssociazioni LA ON
    LA.IDLista = AC.IDLista AND
    LA.IDTipoMacroOggetto = 5 AND
    LA.IDTipoAssociatoCampo = 74 AND
    LA.Deleted = 0 AND
    LA.IDMacroOggetto = 'c3f2c542-a195-11e0-a2e3-000c2962b9f0'
INNER JOIN Campo.Oggetti O ON O.IDOggetto = AC.IDOggetto
WHERE
    OCL.IDCpu = '9e2da792-be47-e311-aea8-b4b52fb677e0' AND
    OCL.Numero > 100 AND
```

You should have, at a minimum, indexes on all of the foreign keys between the tables.

Comment: Great answer. Just curious, why do you consider object name prefixes evil?  You mean like naming a stored proc "usp_GetCustomerList" or, in this case, naming a view "view_myAwesomeView"? ...that last one's a little redundant but you get the point.

Comment: You should know that the object is already a view and down the road what do you do when the view has to become a table (or vice-versa). I've had that happen where a table (tblWhatever) was replaced with a view that went across partitions. Now the name is no longer accurate. Maybe you can refactor it, but that might be difficult. Further, I'm a big proponent of code that is readable and reads naturally. Adding type prefixes to all of your objects hurts that. In the end "evil" is hyperbole, but I think that you gain almost nothing from it, but potentially lose a lot.

Comment: Well put, I didn't consider the case of switching a table to a view; refactoring that could definitely cause some problems.